# App works fine with developer build with xcode. But crashes when run using ipa file

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uitextview, uipageviewcontroller

My app works fine in device from xcode. But crashes when run using ipa file. When I checked the console using organizer, the following error has been displayed

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINibDecoder
>   setScrollEnabled:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

I have used UIPageViewController that displays data in UITextView. Data has been added dynamically using NSOperation to the array , which has been used to display in UITextView.

The error-prone line of code is in DataViewController of the UIPageViewController.
Here is the code

```
    textView=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 290, 500)];
    parentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    [textView setAttributedText:textViewAttributedString];
    [textView setScrollEnabled:NO];
    [textView setBounces:NO];
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
    textView.editable=NO;
    textView.selectable=YES;
    textView.delegate=self;
    textView.tag=currentTextViewTag;
```

Comment: What iOS does the device have? It's crashing at `setScrollEnabled`.

Comment: Add the (symbolicated) stack trace to your question.

Comment: When I enclosed these codes in try catch ,it avoids crashing even if I have not handled that exception . Any solution ?

Comment: @LordZsolt ipad 4 with ios7.1

Comment: `Try-catch` is never the solution. The solution is to prevent it from happening through guards like `respondsToSelector`.